# htaccess not working rewrite rule on live server

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I'm not great at writing rewrite rules. I want to make a rewrite rule for url's of the form

**url:** domain.com/albums.php to
**url:** domain.com/albums

work perfectly but, when i click on specific album not rewrite to below url

**url:** domain.com/albums/album-name

it stuck and shows all albums again. my htaccess rewrite rule is

```
RewriteRule ^albums/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$     /album-gallery.php?albumURL=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^albums$     /album.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with that:

```
Options -MultiViews

# To externally redirect without .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^albums/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$     /album-gallery.php?albumURL=$1 [NC,L]

# To internally rewrite to .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
> server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
> exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
> foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
> files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
> would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
> chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
> document.

So in your case, you have to disable it.

Comment: Thanks! It Works but other pages affected with 404 error. When i add each every page rule in htaccess then other pages works.

Comment: For pages without .php ? I change rules for that.

Comment: As this answer solved your problem, [you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking on **tick mark** on top-left of this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242) Thank you !